# Section in InfoPath form is getting misplaced when deployed

Tags: infopath

I have created new InfoPath form in SharePoint 2010 environment. 
Added some sections there and one condition for that section, which only checks if value not present then hide the section. 
[image: here, how I can see the section while development in Infopath Designer]

But I deploys the form, it is getting misplaced. Highlighted section is misplaced in the form.
[image: Highlighed section is get misplaced here.]

I checked with html with inspect element, it is showing that **align="center"** to one of the div element. 
[image]

and if I open xsl for that perticular view then there is no such alignment added anywhere in the form. 
[image]

So my question is why this is happening ? How to resolve this issue?

Help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

--
Regards,
Prasad

Comment: Are the other changes showing after updating? or is this one specifically?

Comment: This one is specifically. Other sections are working fine.

Comment: give more information about your view layout.

Comment: As shown in first image, its a simple layout, not additional properties are applied.

Comment: Anybody can help  ?

Comment: Do you have access ti the log files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try putting all section in different rows of a table. Mark the row height property to auto and remove highlighting of borders for the table.

**EDIT -** check the indentation settings for the each elements/controls under question, including container table row.

Comment: No, Still same. I have made changes which you have suggested but there is no effect on form design.

Comment: Have you put them in separate rows of the table or all in one row?

Comment: It is already in separate row, Its a separate Table also.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a test list.